# Why are zigbee bulbs so underpowered?

Tags: zigbee, power-consumption, smart-lights

Before switching to smart bulbs I had some pretty strong LED bulbs, which were super bright, and I was very happy with them. I think they were about 14w, maybe less maybe more.

However, after looking around a ton of shops I couldn't find any zigbee bulb with RGB with more than 10W.

The end result is kind of disappointing, even with 4 bulbs in my living room, its kind of a challenge to have the same level of brightness as before.

I wonder, what is the reason for this? How do people for example light their whole house with hue bulbs, when they are so weak?

Is it the zigbee radio, that is the problem? Or am I doing it wrong and I should be looking at another, non bulb, zigbee RGB led solution?

Comment: Are you comparing pure white LED bulbs with Hue/Zigbee RGB LED bulbs?

Comment: Yes. But I also found wifi-rgbs, which are stronger than zigbee rgbs. Is it the rgb part, that makes it hard to make them stronger?

Comment: The reason is marketing. More bulbs - more money.
I'm suffering from the same problem now

Comment: Bulb wattage is far less important than the quoted lumen output. Lumens per watt is an increasing metric and they're probably far better now than they were when this question was asked 4 years ago.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks, maybe ill try again now.

Comment: I recently saw some [Phillips Hue bulbs](https://www.philips-hue.com/en-us/p/hue-white-and-color-ambiance-a21---e26-smart-bulb---100-w/046677562984) (I'm looking at for our church) that output 1600 lumens per bulb at a "100W" rating giving 16 lumen/watt. Whether that's good or bad, I don't know, but that's twice the lumen rating of the bulbs I'm sitting under right now, and these are _plenty_ bright!